# Why doesn't margin-top using percent work in IE7?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer-7

IE7 doesn't seem to understand `top: 106%`:

```
.flex-caption {
  width: 76%;
  margin-left: 170px;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 106%;
  color: #b8b8b8;
  font-size: 14px;
  line-height: 48px;
}
```

http://www.juxt2.com/test/skeleton/index.html

What kind of alternatives do I have?

I'm making a responsive design so I cannot use `px`.

I'm also open to a JavaScript/jQuery fix that would run in only IE7.

Comment: Forgot to post URL: http://www.juxt2.com/test/skeleton/index.html

Comment: There might be a CSS fix, but you're already using JavaScript/jQuery for the slideshow, so you could use JavaScript to fix this problem in a conditional comment for IE7 only. `$(window).resize(function() {
  /* update top value */
});`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But since I am novice in javascript would you please mind to be a little more specific? I mean can you provide a working example?

Answer (score 0):

Trying adding !important next to it. Like :- margin-top !important;